# What laptop supports 4 monitors?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, multiple-monitors

I am using a Windows 7 desktop with 2 video cards and  (2*2=) 4 monitors. I am looking at switching to a laptop. 
Do you have any recommendation for a laptop that would support 4 external monitors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not think any laptop out there supports four monitors out the box - perhaps you could get a dual screen laptop then use an external screen on top to make three, however this would be very expensive.

The other option is to get a few USB graphics cards, I can't really recommend any over any others, but if you Google, you will find hundreds of them.

Alternativly, I know people who have had success with Matrox devices - You could use your laptop screen alongside a [TripleHead2Go](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/).

Comment: pretty much any laptop will support 4 monitors with the little help of external USB graphic cards, however, the mobility of your setup might take a minor hit :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at USB LCD monitors as long as you don't need 3D acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [Ati XGP](http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/ati-xgp/Pages/ati-xgp.aspx). Basically it's a vanilla laptop with an extra, full-fledged external semi-stationary gpu, that you connect with a custom interface.

Edit: Yes, it supports 4 monitors, including the laptops.